Flyway Gradle plugin to run manually using the postgres connection string
I am trying to use https://documentation.red-gate.com/fd/gradle-task-184127407.html to run the flyway migration manually.
In the micronaut application.properties files I have already have a postgres connection
datasources.default.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/school_staff
datasources.default.username=keycloak
datasources.default.password=password
datasources.default.dialect=POSTGRES
datasources.default.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
datasources.default.schema-generate=NONE

In the build.gradle.kts, I have the below configuration
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.flywaydb:flyway-database-postgresql:11.1.0")
    }
}

plugins {
    id("org.flywaydb.flyway") version "11.0.1"
}

flyway {
    url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/school_staff"
    user = "keycloak"
    password = "password"
    locations = arrayOf("classpath:db/migration")
    baselineOnMigrate = true
}

// Ensure classes are built before migration
tasks.named("flywayMigrate").configure {
    dependsOn(tasks.named("classes"))
}

I don't want to configure here again the postgres configuration. How can I pick the application.properties configuration in the gradle flyway configuration.

I have to use below code to achieve this.
import java.util.Properties
// Function to load properties based on the environment
fun loadProperties(env: String): Properties {
    val properties = Properties()
    val propsFile = file("src/main/resources/application-$env.properties")

    if (propsFile.exists()) {
        propsFile.inputStream().use { properties.load(it) }
    } else {
        throw GradleException("Properties file for environment '$env' not found: ${propsFile.absolutePath}")
    }

    return properties
}

// Set the environment (default is 'dev' if no argument is passed)
val env = project.findProperty("env")?.toString() ?: "dev"

// Load properties for the chosen environment
val dbProps = loadProperties(env)



flyway {
    url = dbProps["datasources.default.url"] as String
    user = dbProps["datasources.default.username"] as String
    password = dbProps["datasources.default.password"] as String
    locations = arrayOf("classpath:db/migration")
    baselineOnMigrate = true 
}

